# How to match a list of simple alternating patterns in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching

In R, I have data a vector of integers.

```
run <- sample.int(9, 1000, replace=T)
run[sample.int(1000, 100)] <- NA
```

If at least one of the following patterns, `c(1, x, 1, y)` or `c(x, 1, y, 1)` where `x` and `y` are either whole numbers or NA, is present, I would like to print out the start index of each pattern and update a count variable for each instance of a pattern. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

I was thinking of using the `rle` function and testing for every 4 consecutive values for a length of 1, and then testing whether they conform to one of the patterns. However, I am having problems with NAs with this approach since each NA is treated separately. Perhaps there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking your usage of `sample.int` as implying your vector only contains values from `1:9` and `NA`, here's a regular expressions approach:

```
run <- c(1, NA, 1, 3, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1)
run[is.na(run)] <- 0
pat1 <- "(?=1[0-9]1[0-9])" # using a lookahead assertion around the pattern is a way to allow overlapping matches
pat1.idxs <- unlist(gregexpr(pat1, paste(run, collapse=''), perl=TRUE))
pat1.idxs
# match indexes
# [1] 1 3
length(pat1.idxs)
# counts
# [1] 2
```

Then you would do second pattern similarly.

Comment: +1 - let's mention you assume a vector of digits (which might be what the OP was after but did not make clear.)

Comment: @flodel thanks for your comment. I've made this clear in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of task could be done with the `rollapply` function from the `zoo` package.

```
set.seed(42)
run <- sample.int(9, 1000, replace=T)
run[sample.int(1000, 100)] <- NA

# a list of the patterns
pattern <- list(c(1, NA, 1, NA), c(NA, 1, NA, 1))

library(zoo)

colSums(rollapply(run, length(pattern[[1]]),
                  function(x) sapply(pattern, identical, x)))
```

The result is a vector including the counts of the patterns in the `pattern` list:

```
[1] 0 0
```

*Note*. If the lengths of the patterns were different, `rollapply` had to be executed multiple times.

Comment: So I still have to enumerate all the different possible patterns, i.e. `c(1, x, 1, y)` or `c(x, 1, y, 1)` where `x` and `y` are whole numbers? Is there some way of initializing `x` or `y` to > 0 or something similar?